# decompressing a 50 GB archive to a 100 GB drive

Tags: linux, compression, tar

So I moved hosts today and I put all content from the old host into a single archive. The archive took 20 minutes to compress and one hour to transfer the tar file to the new host (Linux CentOS server). I tried to unzip it, but learned that the disk is too small.

What are my options?

- I want a way to unpack this tar file, and delete it at the same time.
- Could I split the archive into maybe 3 parts? Decompress and delete one at a time? Does anyone know a command that would do this?

Comment: What's the total uncompressed size?

Comment: If you had 100GB free, will that be enough to uncompress the tar file?

Comment: Are you sure that the uncompressed size is less than 100GB?

Comment: You can untar over network..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a nfs share on the first computer and put the tar file there. Mount that share on your second computer and untar it there.

Answer (score 2):

First, make a backup of the 50GB to another computer such as your own computer or a different host.

Second, explain your situation to the new web host. Ask them if you could have them temporarily mount you a special /tmp2 that will have at least 50GB (maybe 55GB). Then have them move your tar file to the /tmp2. Now, that your server has 100GB free, you can uncompress your tar file to the new server.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted support and they have provided me with a solution.

```
cat achive.tar | ssh root@xxx.xxx.xx..xxx tar -xvf - -C /path/to/directory/
```

Basically this command unzips the archive and pipes the data to the remote server at the same time. This is very useful and efficient. The MBps is maxed out when I use this. Meaning that unpacking the data creates no delays.